# Роль суффикса -ник в слове квартирник. Есть ли еще подобные слова?

Tags: суффиксы

Стал объяснять знакомому иностранцу слово *квартирник*. Перевести можно легко: flat party (вечеринка в квартире). Объяснить корень было легко — слово ведь однокоренное с английским *quarters*.

А над суффиксом я задумался. Сначала рассказал, что он [проник в английский язык](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-nik): используется в таких словах, как beatnik, Sputnik, refusenik. Потом стал копать глубже. Стал искать в интернете, и нашел описание четырех ролей этого суффикса:

> Суффикс -ик (-ник) образует существительные, обозначающие:
>
> 1) лицо по свойству или признаку, которые определяют его отношение к предмету, занятию (целинник, химик, очник);
>   2) предмет, предназначенный для чего-либо (чайник, приемник, бумажник);
>   3) предмет, обозначающий книгу или сочинение (задачник, справочник);
>   4) пространство или территорию, покрытые чем-то или содержащие что-то (ельник, малинник).

Кажется, *квартирник* не подходит ни к одному из четырех типов слов. В нашем случае *-ник* обозначает *вечеринка, проходящая в [слово]*.  Интересно, почему вдруг суффикс так "перепрофилировался", и есть ли еще слова с *-ник*, в которых этот суффикс используется таким же образом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примеры употребления слова ***квартирник***:

Давно смекнув, что ни у одной вещи в ее гардеробе нет шанса умереть естественной смертью, она раз в квартал устраивает с подругами ***квартирник***, «обмен-парти», на которую девушки притаскивают то, что надоело, хотя не было толком ношено. [Дмитрий Губин. Жизнь в противотоке // «Огонек», 2013]

Слово за слово, меня пригласили на мой же ***квартирник***. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)]

**Квартира ― квартирник.**

Общим значением  **суффикса НИК** является **предмет, связанный с тем, что названо мотивирующим словом.** В данном случае квартирник ― это вечеринка (предмет), проходящий в квартире (мотивирующее слово).

В русском языке есть существительные  ***девичник*** и ***мальчишник***, образованные **с помощью суффикса НИК.** **Они тоже обозначают вечеринку, но мотивируются не словом квартира**, а словами ***девица, мальчишка*** (не где, а для кого).

Из словаря:

**ДЕВИЧНИК,** -а; м. 1. В русском свадебном обряде: прощальная вечеринка с подругами в доме невесты накануне свадьбы. 2. Нар.-разг. Вечеринка, на которую собираются девушки, женщины.

**МАЛЬЧИШНИК,** -а; м. 1. Прощальная вечеринка с товарищами в доме жениха накануне свадьбы, проходящая одновременно с девичником.2. Разг. Вечеринка, на которую собираются только юноши, молодые мужчины; мужская пирушка.

Comment: Вспомнил - ещё же есть **капустник** (0:

Comment: Да, капустник - самодеятельное представление, шутливо-пародийные сценки на местные темы. Но там значение слова переносное, от капустник - капустный пирог. Происхождение "капустника" связано с Московским Художественным театром. Был Великий пост, поэтому гвоздем постной программы был большой капустный пирог. http://studikam.ru/otkuda-poyavilsya-kapustnik

Answer (score 3):

Здесь "**квартирник**" выступает как неформальное **сокращение** от прилагательного в сочетании с существительным *мужского* рода: **квартирный концерт** или альбом с его записью. Такое понятие возникло в эпоху зарождения того, что сейчас иногда называют "русским роком". В те времена часто записывались концерты, сыгранные на чьей-то из музыкантов квартире, в присутствии узкого круга слушателей. Аналогично образовано слово "**сольник**" (сольный альбом музыканта) и широко употребляемые сокращения от "карманный вор" (карманник), "сметанный кекс" (сметанник), "кадровый работник" (кадровик), "медовый торт" (медовик), "уголовный преступник" (уголовник), (в соотв. контексте) "квартирный вор" (квартирник - здесь тоже существительное мужского рода), "беспризорный ребёнок" (беспризорник)... - таких слов очень много. **Существительное** в таких сокращениях распознаётся из контекста, а на его мужской род намекает этот самый суффикс.